# Hivernal – standalone use and meaning

Tags: grammaire, sens, vocabulaire

Can the word *hivernal* be used by itself and still have meaning. Or would it **only** ever be used in a sentence? Would it look odd to a French-speaker to be seen by itself?

Comment: What do you mean by using a word but not in a sentence?

Comment: Alone, do you mean : Q: *Comment est la météo par chez toi ?* R: *Hivernale!*

Answer (score 2):

> Hivernal

Is an adjective linked to winter, and yes we can use it alone, *see the edit*.
Most of time you will see

> Température Hivernale

Wich means "Temperature from Winter"

Edit : I totally forgot about the use of an adjective in interrogatives or exclamatives ways. Thanks jlliagre and aCOSwt for the reminder !

Comment: Any word can be used in a single word sentence. See aCOSwt comment or simply the reply to : *Quel adjectif est associé à hiver ?*

Comment: I have indeed never been aware of any problem in using whatever adjective alone in interrogatives or exclamatives.

Comment: Indeed, I totally forgot about those way to use and adjective since i always add an interjection with those short sentence. I fixed the response. Sorry for the mistake ! Also ,thanks for the reminder.